# Output at first line of txt file

Tags: batch-file

Got a small script where I need to check if connection was lost with a device and when it was lost. Issue I ran into is that I can't find a way to output ping, date and time into first line of the txt file.

My script writes down info 2020/02/21 10:56 2020/02/21 10:57 2020/02/21 10:58 but I need time written in different order, from newest to oldest. Like this 2020/02/21 10:58 2020/02/21 10:57 2020/02/21 10:56.

Would this be possible to achieve?

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
date /T>> PingLog.txt
time /T >> PingLog.txt
ping 192.168.0.2 -n 4 >> PingLog.txt
TIMEOUT 10
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

I just this and it is working:

```
type logs.txt >> PingLog.txt
type PingLog.txt > logs.txt
del PingLog.txt
```

Comment: So don't append but rather prepend your information to the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a temporary file to create the latest ping log, then append the old log to it using either a **for loop** or the **redirected output of the type command**. Delete the old Log, and rename the temporary file to the name of the old log.

enter the following in cmd.exe and read the output.

- `For /?`
- `Ren /?`
- `Type /?`
- `Del /?`